# Show new comment notice when viewing post in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, comments, ios-app

Can we get an indicator for newly arrived comments while viewing a post, as we do on the desktop site?

> <sup>add / show **2** more comments</sup>

Or maybe just load the new comments immediately...?

Furthermore, new comments should *automatically* load when posting a comment (again, like the desktop). Several times I've found that when adding a comment what I had to say had already been said, but I never saw the other comments until manually refreshing the post.